# Why does the string of a simple pendulum need to be perfectly flexible?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, string, elasticity

The book says:

> "The string should be perfectly flexible, if we like to neglect the effects of different velocities of the different parts of the string during the oscillation."

Can anyone explain what actually is going on over here? I mean how does the different velocities of different parts of the string affect the system?

Comment: If the string itself provides any resistance to the motion, then there are internal forces acting there not being considered.

Comment: In my judgment, what they meant to say was that the string must be perfectly inextensible.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that the string was not perfectly flexible but instead was a length of steel wire, rigidly fixed at its upper end. Then when the weight on its other end tries to swing back and forth, the springiness of the wire applies an extra restoring force in addition to that generated by gravity and the resonant frequency of the pendulum will shift to a higher value.

Comment: Good point, there should be no torque originating at the point of support.  If the string were to actually flex along its length, then the effective length would change. We normally assume that the string has negligible mass. Otherwise, the calculations get complicated.